# How to insert existing data into auto-incrementing field

Tags: sql-server, insert, auto-increment

I used the SMAA to upsize an Access 2010 database to SQL Server 2005.

During the process a number of records were not imported into SQL Server due to some corrupt or illegal data.  I have since cleaned up the data that was not imported and saved it to a temporary table in the database.  I now want to insert that data into the original table.  However, one of the fields, called `Task_ID`, is an `auto-incrementing` field.  When I run a standard insert query, the resulting data `auto-incremented` and does not use the imported `Task_ID` value.  Is there a way to get this data into the field without it being changed?

Answer (score 2):

Enable insertion of existing data for the upload, then turn it off again.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259221(v=sql.80).aspx explains how:

Basically it is a SQL commmand. The syntax is:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [ database. [ owner. ] ] { table } { ON | OFF }
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the `INSERT` statements with the `SET IDENTITY_INSERT` command:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [table_name] ON

...

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [table_name] OFF
```

Comment: Thanks guys.  I thought it would be something like the Identity_Insert command.  Unfortunately, it does not appear to be that simple.  I'm getting the error:

Comment: Try this again.  Thanks guys.  I thought it would be something like the Identity_Insert command.  Unfortunately, it does not appear to be that simple.  I'm getting the error: "Explicit value must be specified for identity column in table 'TaskList'.  The Identity column in this table is 'Task', which is the PK and which is not in my INSERT or SELECT statement because it is not in the table to be imported from.  Is there another way to get around the auto-increment issue without conflicting with the PK?

Comment: I'm trying to narrow this down.  I've created a new table of the historical data that includes all columns including the PK.  When I try to do an INSERT using the IDENTITY_INSERT parameter I get a violation of the PK.  I've tried using WHERE NOT EXIST to only insert the data if the PK value does not exist but I'm not making any progress.  Can anyone provide me with a starting point on this?

Comment: @user3178144: Is the PK an identity column? If so, is it *included* in the `INSERT` and `SELECT`? The bottom line is this, *if you're going to `INSERT` into the identity column,* then you need to `SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON`. If you're going to `SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON`, then you *need to `INSERT` into the identity.* If you want it to build its own identities, leave `IDENTITY_INSERT` alone and *do not include the PK in the `INSERT` and `SELECT`.*

Comment: You have to use explicit column lists for insert/select operation. Then you need to be sure that your PK doesn't already exists in destination - or, if duplicates need to be allowed, you have to create just another PK. Then you need to remember, that only one table can have identity insert enabled at the same time.